# testing library userEvent.selectOptions does not select option

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, user-event

I have a React component which renders a combobox (another external component) with an option. When deployed the component does work as expected.

```
<select class="country-select"
         id="nationalityCode" name="nationalityCode" required="">
    <option value="" disabled="" hidden="">Choose</option>
    <optgroup label="Most used">
        <option value="0052">Belgium</option>
        <option value="0055">German Citizien</option>
        <option value="0057">French</option>
        <option value="0001">Dutch</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Alle Nationalities">
        <option value="0052">Belgium</option>
        <option value="0055">German Citizien</option>
        <option value="0057">French</option>
        <option value="0001">Dutch</option>
        <option value="0050">Albanese</option>
        <option value="0223">American Citizen</option>

    </optgroup>
</select>
```

When using testing library userEvent.selectOptions, the select of an option is successfull. Only the expect fails with

```
Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: true
Received: false
```

When debugging the selection state for all options it shows that the initial selected option is selected.

```
    if (changeValue.nationaliteit) {
        const selectOption = screen.getAllByRole('option', { name: 'French' })[0];
        await userEvent.selectOptions(
            screen.getByRole('combobox', { name: 'Nationaliteit' }),
            selectOption
        );
        expect(
            (screen.getAllByRole('option', { name: 'French' })[0] as HTMLOptionElement).selected
        ).toBe(true);
    }
```

Using

```
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
```

Comment: You have `{ name: 'Nationaliteit' }` but your `select` element  is not named like that.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. A working example:

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <label>Nationaliteit
      <select id="nationalityCode" name="nationalityCode" >
        <option>Choose</option>
        <optgroup label="Most used">
          <option value="0052">Belgium</option>
          <option value="0055">German Citizien</option>
          <option value="0057">French</option>
          <option value="0001">Dutch</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Alle Nationalities">
          <option value="0052">Belgium</option>
          <option value="0055">German Citizien</option>
          <option value="0057">French</option>
          <option value="0001">Dutch</option>
          <option value="0050">Albanese</option>
          <option value="0223">American Citizen</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </label>
  )
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import React from "react"
import { MyComponent } from './'

describe('74627696', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    render(<MyComponent />);
    const listbox = screen.getByRole('combobox', { name: 'Nationaliteit' });
    const selectOption = screen.getAllByRole('option', { name: 'French' })[0]
    await user.selectOptions(listbox, selectOption)
    expect((screen.getAllByRole('option', { name: 'French' })[0] as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/74627696/index.test.tsx (20.691 s)
  74627696
    ✓ should pass (406 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        22.071 s, estimated 31 s
```

package version:

```json
"react": "^16.14.0",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
```